# Turning on IRFZ44N using a BC548 transistor and an ESP32

Tags: arduino, transistors, mosfet, dc-motor, esp32

I'm working on my personal project for school. In this, I want to run 12 V 1 A motor using a **IRFZ44N** MOSFET using an ESP32 but as we know, the IRFZ44N needs 4 V to completely turn on and ESP32 pins provide only 3.3 V at 20 mA, sonot enough to turn on MOSFET.

I searched the internet for the proper transistor and I found a common transistor (BC548) which is in my box now. I have drawn a circuit to drive the IRFZ44N.  Will it work?

[image]

Comment: "as we know, the IRFZ44N needs 4 V to completely turn on". Absolutely not! 4V is the threshold voltage where an IRFZ44 is guaranteed to conduct only 0.00025A. The Vgs must be 10V for all of them to fully turn on. An IRLZ44 needs 5V to fully turn on. Why is the BC548 transistor added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simulation of the circuit, showing a 3.3V GPIO signal driving a 1 amp motor (simulated by a 100 mH inductor with 12 ohms series resistance)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6x8Qg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Voltages]

[image: Motor Current]

Comment: Thanks! it's physically working now! I wonder how can I control its direction both ways in future! I don't need it running both ways for now but I'm just curious to know! Thanks!!

Comment: @AkashPatil THAT needs to be addressed in another question, but you can find that information all over the Internet and StackExchange. In short, you need an H-bridge circuit to be able to change direction of the motor.

Answer (score 4):

The transistor needs to be connected with its emitter tied to ground, called "common emitter".

As you have it, in a configuration called "emitter follower" or "common collector", the emitter of the transistor is always 0.7V below the base, and since the base never rises above +3.3V, the emitter can only reach +2.6V. That's not even close to what you require at M1's gate.

In the following circuit, M1's gate is +5V when the ESP32 output is low (0v), and 0V when that output is +3.3V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK3Exq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To switch the motor on, you require a *low* output from the ESP32.

R2 prevents the motor from running before the ESP32 has configured its ports, by gently holding that output high.

---

#### Update:

I just noticed that you can further improve this by connecting the top of R3 to the +12V supply, instead of +5V. That way, M1's gate can rise to 12V, easily enough to get the best (lowest) possible drain-source resistance \$R_{DS(ON)}\$.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your MOSFET will never turn on. If your GPIO high is 3.3V, the BC548 emitter will be about 2.6V to 2.7V because of the base-emitter PN junction voltage drop.
To solve this, you should use the BC548 as common-emitter configuration to drive the MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Sorry, I have never heard anything about common-emitter configuration. If possible, can you draw a simple schema with a pen and upload?

Comment: Move R2 to the collector side and emitter to GND. Then connect gate of Q2 to collector.

Comment: @PStechPaul Is this a right way?  https://ibb.co/C70PZty

Comment: Yes, that will work. But you need a logic high from the ESP32 GPIO to turn it off. Also make sure you have a capacitor across your 12V supply, and a flyback diode on the motor.

Comment: @PStechPaul Can I add another BC548 Transistor for proper switching as ESP32 3.3v logic high to turn on Mosfet and 3.3v logic low to turn of mosfet. My update schema: https://ibb.co/Tbz6Bqr

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: Many tell you the right way to do it. I don't need to repeat after them.